# How do I take a full-screen screenshot with the status bar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

This is my extention snapshot() function Code

```
extension View {
    func snapshot() -> UIImage {
        let size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.main.bounds.width,UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.ignoresSafeArea())
        let view = controller.view
        view?.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        return renderer.image { _ in
            view?.drawHierarchy(in:CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

[My View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKwYi.png)

I get the following result, which is obviously incorrect because the image is without status bar.

[After Taking Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYHhu.png)

Comment: You are setting the size to the whole screen. That´s why this is happening.

Comment: I appreciate your response to my query, @burnsi however I've already tried that and the result was a cropped image without a status bar.

Comment: I think when you are saying “status bar”  I think you mean the “navigation bar”. The “status bar” is what has the time in it. The snapshot screenshot looks like you are passing in only the `View` that is wrapped in the `NavigationStack`.  If you passed in the `NavigationStack` view then the snapshot would capture that.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkT. But the status bar wasn't captured in the snapshot, that’s my issue. I just use NavigationStack to show my captured image.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have used ignoresSafeArea, which ignores the top and bottom safe area

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self.ignoresSafeArea())
```

To generate full screenshorts with safeArea, use this:-

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
```